# character encoding of table name is being changed at runtime: PDO_ODBC

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am running Windows 10 and PHP version 5.6.8 and Apache as server, using PDO_ODBC to connect with an MS Access database. Some of the table names are in Japanese and some of the table names are in English. I am trying to run select queries on these tables.

The tables with names in English are returning the result but the table names which are in Japanese are returning the table but the values characters are being changed in unrecognised characters.

I have checked the log file, after checking the log file I come to know that the characters of the table name is changed and this is the reason why I am not getting any result from the table.

Here is what I am getting in the log file.

> ERROR - 2016-04-03 16:37:29 --> -1305 - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: -1305 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'ŒÚ‹q‚l'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly. (SQLExecute[-1305] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) with query: "SELECT * FROM ŒÚ‹q‚l WHERE recID = 2;" in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsPaper\fuel\core\classes\database\pdo\connection.php on line 272

Comment: Have you tried setting the PHP character set (e.g., `default_charset`) and encoding of your PHP source files to cp932?

Comment: @Grod thompson Yes i have tried to do that but no luck.

Is there anyone who can tell me that why this question have got downvote.
If You can't answer or can't understand the question please leave the question as it is.
I am gonna answer this very soon. Behold the answer is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem after making one change in the `httpd.conf` file.
I have added `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` line in this file and saved the file.
After saving the file I restarted the server and everything was fixed now the results returned from the database are in showing in Japanese.